# How to scroll back through the command line history in the Emacs interactive subshell?

Tags: shell, commands, history

Let us say in the interactive subshell I run these commands:

- `command_a`
- `command-b`
- `command_c`
- ...
- `command_z`

I type <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> to go back to `command_z`. 
But how can I scroll back the history of commands until I land on  `command_j`, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cycling the command history in Shell use:
`M-n` and `M-p`

have a look at [Gnu Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Ring.html#Shell-Ring) for the Shell ring

Comment: I landed on that page before asking, but I guess I am not smart :) Thank you for the help.

Comment: emacs documentation requires getting used to. It is very minimal yet concise. You are welcome!